# Why aren't my program's functions occurring correctly?

Tags: c++, boolean-expression

(This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I can word it better.)

I have a program that lets you open either a calculator or a "number generator". You pick which one to open by entering C or N into the console. The code is pretty complex for me as I just started learning C++ and so I wasn't really able to scope out any issues with it. Also, I have defined all the variables shown and included .

However, no matter what I enter at the beginning (even if it's an invalid answer, like Q or 123), it opens the calculator.

```
void init()
{
    std::cout << "Open calculator or number generator? ( C or N ): ";
    std::cin >> firstpick;
}

int main()
{
    init();
    if (firstpick == 'c' || 'C')
        calculator();
    else if (firstpick == 'n' || 'N')
        numbergen();
    else if (firstpick != 'c' && 'n' && 'C' && 'N')
        std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid answer to init";

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is to allow me to open either C or N and to have the program return an error when I enter an invalid answer, but it always opens C no matter what.

Comment: Your code simply will not compile, so its behaviour is moot.

Comment: `if (firstpick == 'c' || 'C')` is always true

Comment: More relevent: `'C'` is always true.

Comment: Also, which C++ book are you learning from that suggests you write code that looks anything like this?

Comment: change that to `if (firstpick == 'c' || firstpick == 'C')` and also change the other if statements in the same way. you cannot chain || or && the way you are doing it.

Comment: Change `if (firstpick == 'c' || 'C')` to `if (firstpick == 'c' || firstpick == 'C')` and other conditions accordingly.

Comment: None of these suggestions work if `firstpick` is not defined.

Comment: @NeilButterworth good catch. if his code is compiling, then perhaps he has it declared as a global variable which is probably what he did since he's attempting to use it from two different functions.

Comment: @Chris Maybe. Maybe not. It's not a good idea to guess when you could get the OP to post the actual code.

Comment: I mean, I don't see `#include <iostream>` either which is another reason this code wont compile

Comment: @Chris The point of my original comment exactly. Who knows what he has actually written?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; the entire script refused to fit in the code section for some reason. I did include <iostream> and define all the variables. Babak Naffas solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`firstpick == 'c' || 'C'` will always return `true`.

`firstpick == 'c'` may evaluate to `false` but the 2nd half of the statement is just `'C'` which, as a none-zero value, will evaluate to `true`.

Change your logic to `if (firstpick == 'c' || firstpick == 'C')` and follow the same pattern for the number generator logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
if (firstpick == 'c' || 'C' != 0)
```

to get your effect you need to do...

```
if (firstpick == 'c' || firstpick == 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You write your if functions wrongly.

`||` logical OR separates two logical conditions of which at least one should be true to produce `true` value as result.

In your case conditions checked by the first "if" are:

1. `firstpick == 'c'` and
2. `'C'`

So your if is going to produce `true` if 1. or 2. or both are true.

Of course as you can see now 2. is always true so the whole if always returns `true`.

Try change your ifs like this:

`if (firstpick == 'c' || firstpick == 'C')`

And it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define what firstpick is so the code you presented cant compile. You also need to return a char from your initialization function. This code below should do what you need. Also you need to "or" individual comparisons in your if statements.

```
#include<iostream>
char init()
{
    std::cout << "Open calculator or number generator? ( 1 or 2 ): ";
    char option;
    std::cin >> option;
    return option;
}

int main()
{
    int firstpick=init();
    if (firstpick == 'c'|| firstpick == 'C')
        std::cout<<"calculator\n";
    else if (firstpick == 'n' || firstpick == 'N')
        std::cout<<"Num gtenerator\n";
    else
        std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid answer to init\n";

    return 0;
}
```